# ID mode problem in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

**Problem:**

I am using Visual studio 2010 MFC c++..

[facing this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbolv.jpg)

I need actual menus that i naked, but i am in edit ID mode by mistake how can i leave edit mode.. and when i click on  any edit ID mode menu.. i received the message provided in the above link

and when i run the project.. it shows no error but even then MFC is not running and displaying the result.Any one can help me to get rid of from thim problem

Expecting a good response..
Thanks

Comment: You are not expressing your problem clearly enough for us to help. What action are you taking? What are you expecting to happen? What is happening instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you're trying to ask but...
maybe edit the resource file as text would help?

Comment: well, you can see in the link, i am seeing ID mode of menu.. that i do't need it...I want to excess my actual menus..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are in ID edit mode and want to leave it. Right click somewhere on empty space and uncheck 'Edit IDs' in the context menu by clicking on it.